# show $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^{\ast}b_i$ is convergent using the Schwarz inequality

Tags: mathematical-physics

**Question:**
Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be in $\mathbb{C}^\infty$.  Show $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^{\ast}b_i$ is convergent, using in particular the Schwarz inequality.

**Attempt at answer:**

$\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ both in $C^\infty$, which is the set of all complex sequences. A property of $C^\infty$ says that a complex sequence $|a\rangle =\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |\alpha_i|^2$ is finite.

So, let $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ and $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be sequences in $C^\infty$. Then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |\alpha_i|^2$ and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty |\beta_i|^2$ are both finite, meaning $|a>$ and $|b>$ are finite, which implies that $|\langle a|b\rangle|^2$ is finite. Then, by the Schwarz Inequality, we have $|\langle a|b\rangle|^2\leq$ $\langle a|a\rangle \langle b|b\rangle$ also finite.

Then, since $|a\rangle $ is finite, then $|a^\ast \rangle$ is finite. So, $ \langle a^\ast|a^\ast \rangle \langle b|b\rangle$ is finite.

Thus, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i^\ast\beta_i$ is finite, and so convergent.

Comment: You need some assumption on $(a_i)$ an $(b_i)$...

Comment: You're missing the premise that $\sum \lvert a_n\rvert^2 < \infty$ and $\sum \lvert b_n\rvert^2 < \infty$.

Comment: That's all the information I'm given. I guess that's why I'm stumped.

Comment: Well, let $a_i = i,\, b_i = (-1)^i$ for something that obviously doesn't converge.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean? Proof by contradiction?

Comment: Without additional restrictions on $a_i$ and $b_i$, the sum doesn't need to converge, the statement is false. That makes proving it kind of hard. I'm pretty sure the premise mentioned above got lost somewhere, no idea whether you overlooked it, or the author of the exercise forgot to state it.

Comment: A little example of Daniel's statement: if the sequences a and b are both 1, 2, 3, ... your sum just can't converge.

Comment: That's the part that's confusing me. The whole point of the problem is that it DOES converge.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says
$$
\sum_k|a_kb_k|\le\left(\sum_k|a_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_k|b_k|^2\right)^{1/2}
$$